# what is the pod termination time?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to know when the pod goes under termination and how much time it takes for termination

from which stage pod go under termination

I have a cluster in gke and so I want to know the details about pod termination in gke

Comment: A large component is how long the program running inside the pod takes to clean up and exit.

Comment: By default, all deletes are graceful within 30 seconds. The kubectl delete command supports the --grace-period=<seconds> option which allows you to override the default and specify your own value.

Answer (score 1):

The default grace period is 30 seconds if that is what you are looking for.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination